# About convergence of infinite products

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{ z_n \} \subset \mathbb{C}$ $z_n \neq 0$. I'm trying to prove that convergence of  $\Pi z_n$ is equivalent to:

$\forall \epsilon>0$  $\exists $ $\nu>0$ such that  if $n>\nu$  $|z_{n+1}······z_{n+k}-1|<\epsilon$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a complete convergence equals Cauchy-Sequence. My problem starts when I try to prove that the statement from above implies the sequence of partial products is Cauchy.

How can i show that (with the property from above) $\exists K>0$  such that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$   $\quad$$| \prod_{n=1}^{N} z_n|<K?$

Comment: You seem to be confused on the definition of Cauchy sequence. Let $P_n$ be the $n$-th partial product.  The Cauchy condition in this context is: $\forall\,\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N$ such that $n,m\ge N\implies |P_n-P_m|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, but if n<m  $|P_n-P_m|=|\Pi^n z_n||1- \Pi_{n+1}^{n+k}z_n|$  where n+k=m

Comment: Sure but that is nothing like what you've written in your original post.

Comment: Hmm, maybe i expressed myself badly. What i mean, is  $|P_n-P_m|=|\Pi^n z_n||1- \Pi_{n+1}^{n+k}z_n|$ if i know how to control   $|1- \Pi_{n+1}^{n+k}z_n|$ can i find a way to control  $|\Pi^n z_n|$ and get convergence?

Comment: You can solve this problem by fixing a large $N$ and using that $|P_n - P_m| \leq |P_n - P_N| + |P_m - P_N|$, and now you can use the inequality with a fixed $\prod_{k=1}^N z_k.$

Comment: @PedroM. could you please explain this a little bit? I got: $|P_n - P_m| \leq |P_n - P_N| + |P_m - P_N| =| \Pi z_n||1-z_{n+1}··z_N|+|\Pi z_m||1-z_{m+1}···z_N|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ in the property, we have the existence of a $\nu$ such that

$$\left\lvert 1 - \prod_{m=1}^k z_{n+m}\right\rvert < \frac{1}{2}$$

for all $n > \nu$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$. In particular,

$$\frac{1}{2} < \left\lvert \prod_{m=1}^k z_{n+m}\right\rvert < \frac{3}{2}$$

for all $n > \nu$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Then it follows that

$$\frac{1}{2} \min \left\{ \left\lvert \prod_{n=1}^k z_n\right\rvert : k \leqslant \nu+1 \right\} \leqslant \left\lvert \prod_{n=1}^N z_n\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{3}{2} \max \left\{ \left\lvert \prod_{n=1}^k z_n\right\rvert : k \leqslant \nu+1\right\},$$

which shows that all partial products are bounded away from $0$ and from $\infty$. Hence a further application of the property shows that the sequence of partial products is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: shouldn't I show that this bound doesnt depend on k?

Comment: We take the minimum resp. maximum over $\lvert P_k\rvert$ for $k \leqslant \nu+1$, thus the bounds only depend on $\nu$. Choosing the minimal possible $\nu$ of course gives the tightest bounds.